# Firebase Rules: How to block anonymous access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Reading the Firebase Rules [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) I couldn't find anything on how to block anonymous access to a specific collection or document.

In other words, I want to block users who are not logged in, and I also want to block users who are logged in as anonymous. I want to allow only users who are logged in as themselves (through email, Facebook, Google, SMS, etc).

How can I do that?

This is the code I came up with, which doesn't work:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        }
        match /collectionExample/{documentExample} {
          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.isAnonymous != false;              
          allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I suspect you can use `request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider` (see the docs for [`auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth)).  It's supposed to contain the value `anonymous` for anonymous auth.  So, to allow document creates for non-anonymous logged in users:

```
allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous';
```

Or, you could change it to only allow certain providers as well, given the other possible values for token `firebase.sign_in_provider` in the docs.

Comment: I tested, using `request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous'`, that works, thanks