# Firebase -Prevention Rules for Anonymous Users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have Anonymous enabled. My current Rules lets users who are authenticated read from certain refs. How can I add a rule that **prevents** Anonymous users from reading from certain refs considering their `auth.uid isn't nil`

[image]

Rules:

```
"users": { // anonymous users shouldn't be able to read/write to the ref
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
}
```

Node Example:

```
"users" // all of these users aren't anonymous
    -uid123
    -uid456
    -uid789
```

Comment: You could probably use the answer here and change to "allow read" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419498/firebase-rules-how-to-block-anonymous-access

Comment: Also see the top upvoted, but not accepted, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588169/firebase-rules-anonymous-and-authentificated